# CSS won't dynamically change with .addClass() or .css()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table that has rows with different classes depending on what color it should be.  On the click of a button I want the background color of the row to change instantly.  I tried both `.addClass()` and `.css()` but they both fail. On click, I have a function that checks whether the row is colored or not, that works fine.

Here are the pieces of code I'm using and the css classes that go along with the rows.

**If a row is white:**

`$("#"+table+"_row_"+id).addClass("table-1").removeClass("table-0");`

or

`$("#"+table+"_row_"+id).css("background-color","orange");`

**If a row is orange:**

`$("#"+table+"_row_"+id).addClass("table-0").removeClass("table-1");`

or

`$("#"+table+"_row_"+id).css("background-color","white");`

**css:**

```
table.tablesorter .table-1{
background-color:orange;
}
table.tablesorter .table-0{
background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: what kind of reward are we talkin? :)

Comment: Inspect the row after clicking. Make sure the class / styles are applied and if so, find out if anything is overriding them

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that `"#"+table+"_row_"+id` won't give you the element you want. Check if that selector gives you any elements at all, and verify they are the right one.

Comment: @Jason if you have to ask, you're not ready for it ;)

Comment: HTML sample, alert(table) and alert(id) please?

Comment: @Phil I do inspect and nothing changes

Comment: @Golez I was thinking the same but assumed he'd already checked that

Comment: If you feel certain that your jQuery is performing as it should, double check that you aren't explicitly setting background colors of td tags elsewhere in your CSS.

Comment: @Trevor When you say "nothing changes", do you mean the class / style changes are not happening on the element? As in, the attributes themselves are no different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that `"#"+table+"_row_"+id` won't give you the element you want. Check if that selector gives you any elements at all, and verify they are the right one.

I prefer to use classes only for this, because else you're still embedding style in code while you just got it out of your html. You can use hasClass to do this.

Speed things up by storing the reference:

```
var x = $('#'+table+'_row_'+id);
if (x.hasClass('table-0'))
{
  x.addClass('table-1').removeClass('table-0');
}
else
{
  x.addClass('table-0').removeClass('table-1');
}
```

It makes debugging and updating easier too, since you know that if x is right once, it will always be right. And you can inspect it easier too.

Comment: You are right, `id` kept returning undefined until I set it to a var.  Weird. Thanks for pointing this stuff out.

Comment: Golez, please share with us what you received as a reward

Comment: @Karpie Everything about javascript/jquery is weird in my opinion.

Comment: @golez dang. i was hoping for treasure or a limerick or a beer or something :\

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the CSS cascading order, perhaps with Firebug or WebKit's Web inspector?

When updating a CSS class, you'll need to take care the [cascading order](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/structure.html#cascade). Otherwise, it may not turn out to be the effect you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle. It is a stripped down version of what I believe you're trying to make work. http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/ntPGb/1/